# Get status for a list of items

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a dynamodb table with a partition key for client_id and no sort key. The json stored in the table just contains the client_id and compliance_level (which is a string title). I need to query the table for a list of client_id's because there is an application that displays client information in a tabular display. I am trying to use ExpressionFilter but get an "Error ValidationException: Either the KeyConditions or KeyConditionExpression parameter must be specified in the request." exception. I don't however have a keycondition to query on. Any assistance would be appreciated. I can't use batchgetitem as there will be more than 100 items to get the status for.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region: 'ap-southeast-2'});

var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

var params = {
    TableName : "Client-Compliance",
    ProjectionExpression: "username, version",
    FilterExpression : "client_id IN (:client1, :client2)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues : {
        ":client1" : { "S": "c1234567" },
        ":client2" : { "S": "c88888888" }
    }
};

ddb.query(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Many thanks

Comment: `query` queries within a specific Partition Key, so you would need to provide a `KeyConditionExpression:"client_id=:client_id_value"`. So you most likely need a Partition Key of say 'CLIENT' and a Sort Key with their actual id. Or create a GSI using the client_id as a Sort Key (and a PK that is the same for all items) and query on that index instead.

Comment: **KeyConditionExpression:**  _This allows Query to retrieve one item with a given partition key value and sort key value, or several items that have the same partition key value but different sort key values._ https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-request-KeyConditionExpression